# Errors compiling template: tag <v-toolbar> has no matching end tag

Tags: vue.js

I started working with Vue.js but I try to implement `v-toolbar` but it gives me the following error:

```
Errors compiling template: tag <v-toolbar> has no matching end tag.
```

mi code:

```
            <template>
        <div class="building">
          <v-app>
            <v-toolbar>
              <v-toolbar-title>audi</v-toolbar-title>
            <v-toolbar>
          </v-app>
        </div>
        </template>


        <style>
        .building{
        background:url("./assets/scss/images/HomeBackground.jpg");
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        background-size:100% 100%;
        }

        #app {
          font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
          text-align: center;
          color: #2c3e50;
        }

        #navold {
          padding: 30px;
        }

        #navold a {
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #2c3e50;
        }

        #navold a.router-link-exact-active {
          color: #42b983;
        }
        </style>
```

I'm really new to this, but I already have the NPM and Vue version installed, I don't know if I'm missing something or I'm doing something wrong

[image]

Comment: An end tag looks like </v-toolbar> ... you are using <v-toolbar> for start and end

Answer (score 2):

add `/` to `<v-toolbar>` on line 6

```
<v-toolbar>
    <v-toolbar-title>audi</v-toolbar-title>
</v-toolbar>  <----- here
```